# Why isn't this answer considered as low quality?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I'm talking about [this answer from `How should I get list from string in Python?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55389255/7655838)

He literally said:

> Declare an empty list at beginning.. Iterate through the dictionary and append each item to the list.
>
> Print the list outside the loop once entire iteration is completed.

He didn't show any code, while the other answers do show examples in code to solve the problem. I flagged it as low-quality and my flag was declined.

**Are people allowed to answer a question without code, just explaining what to do (without code nor pseudocode)?**

I thought that the idea of SO was to show quick and simple Q/A site. Showing code is a straight and fast way to find a solution. Instead, reading a paragraph and then writing your interpretation of it in code is slower. Even more, it can cause a problem for inexperienced people (which may misunderstand what the answerer said).

In this case, the answer is quite simple, so I don't think it would be a huge effort from the answerer to post a code example.

Or maybe am I misunderstanding the purpose of SO?

Comment: Does it represent an honest attempt to answer the question?  Seems like it, to me.  In which case, it's not a very *good* answer, by any means.  So downvote it.

Comment: Quick and simple isn't really the design of the site, it just happens that sometimes it works out that way as a byproduct. While code is encouraged, with questions like this which seem to be homework related, often psuedocode is offered in order to teach the user how to fish so to speak. That they are forced to write their own code (even if it isn't perfect) is better for them in the long run in this scenario.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you explain to me I could try to fix it.

Comment: I see two reasons for downvotes (actually surprisingly low number of downvotes): people disagree that this is VLQ answer (most posts on meta voted as agree/disagree even if not marked "feature-request"); post does not show research effort (search for [SO purpose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=purpose) - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292175/what-is-the-purpose-of-stack-overflow and search for https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=code+required+answer finds https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326706/answer-a-language-specific-question-in-pseudocode-to-explain-logic)

Comment: Very low quality flags are handled by moderators. The only thing we can do to fix the problem that you can’t is *delete* the answer. So, if deletion is not appropriate, then you should not flag as VLQ. Yes, moderators can edit to improve the answer, but only if we know the technology. Of course, you too have the ability to edit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> He didn't show any code

It isn't a requirement.

> while the other answers do show examples in code to solve the problem.

If you find other answers better, give them a up-vote, if you don't like an answer because you don't think it's useful, give it a down-vote.

> I flagged it as low-quality and my flag was declined.

The flag is called **very low quality** with the description being:

> This answer has ***severe formatting*** or ***content problems***. This answer is ***unlikely to be salvageable through editing***, and might need to be removed.*'.

(emphasis mine)

Do you sincerely believe that it falls under that category?

> Are people allowed to answer a question without code, just explaining what to do (without code nor pseudocode)?

Absolutely. However, people *may* react differently to those answers.

If you still feel that the answer is not useful or is not as good as it should be, then show that by voting.

Answer (score 11):

1. Not all answers *require* code. It's a courtesy and has a better chance of making what you said clearer, but by no means is it mandatory.
2. Flags aren't meant to be used to indicate that an answer is wrong or not helpful; *downvotes* are.
3. You judge an answer on its own merits and usefulness.  If you believe that the answer was not useful because it lacked example code, it would be fair to vote on that premise.